# wget and special characters

Tags: character-encoding, wget

I am using wget locally to take a static snapshot of a small web app. When I do, the resulting html files come back with strange characters in place of quotation marks and apostrophes.

What can I do to avoid this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you examining the resulting files?  It's quite likely that the file has UTF-8 encoding, and you need to examine them in an editor or web browser that understands that they are UTF-8.

Comment: @Brett How did you solve this problem?

Comment: @AngelTsankov, it's been awhile now, but I don't think I ever found a solution.

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest trying with:

```
--restrict-file-names=nocontrol
```

Source: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/misc/wget.html

Comment: Thank you! I was a having a slightly different but related issue, and this option (though with `ascii` instead of `nocontrol`) finally gave me the solution I needed. Somehow I skipped over it when reading the wget man.

Comment: using termux the solution i needed was with `vms` so an address with a query string would turn the `?` into `@`. you can see the options by offering no option or a wrong one.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you need to specify `--remote-encoding` perhaps `--remote-encoding=utf-8`.

Comment: I tried that (should have mentioned that in my question) and got "wget: unrecognised option '--remote-encoding=utf-8'. --remote-encoding doesn't show up when I call -h for help either. Could that be because I'm on windows?

Comment: And you're sure that your local terminal locale settings are correct?

Comment: Which version of `wget` are you running? `wget --version`.

Comment: I think so. I haven't changed anything.

Comment: Maybe a newer version is the easiest path for you? [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=wget%20win32%201.13) has some suggestions, mind I've not tested any of these.

Comment: Hi all, I have similar issue, im using wget 1.10.2, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you provide a url and a wget command-line that exhibits the issue?

Comment: It was a script written by someone else that contains the following line: `wget --timeout=7200 --directory-prefix=$SCRAPE_DATA_DIRECTORY -np -nd --user-agent "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0)" --level 0 -p -i $URL_FILE` thanks

Comment: And which urls exhibit the problem in `$URL_FILE`?

Comment: the actual error appears in the javascript of the **home** file `PC_7_0_CVM_thisBusinessUnit.Articles[0] = new Array("http://intranet-stg.global.xxxxxxx.com/News/HT/Pages/Manyappyreturns.aspx",htmlDecode("Many appâ€™y returns" ),"4 Sep");`
And the url is just the normal url of the page downloaded `http://qawps.au.xxxxxxxxxx.com/wps/portal/home` contained in $URL_FILE

Comment: notice above I was trying to htmlDecode the line "Many app???y returns" (i put question marks to mean the funny character), but it didn't work when it supposed to be a `**right single quote, i.e. &#8217;**`

Comment: It's hard to say anything about this without being able to reproduce the effect.

Comment: I had a problem with encoding that led me to this answer, even though it wasn't the same problem. `--local-encoding=utf-8` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem but then I found out that my browser showed the web page with wrong enconding. For example in Firefox I just needed to change View -> Character Encoding -> Unicode.

Comment: This solved the problem also for me, but only for one page. After navigating to the next page downloaded by wget I had again to change Firefox's encoding to Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

I had such issue too. It appeared the page I was downloading were gziped.
You can check this using the -S option in wget. 
You will find a

> Content-Encoding: gzip

line. In such case I use zcat to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `wget` can't guess the encoding so you need this in your html response of your web app:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Answer (score 0):

I had this vary same problem (a `wget` mirror with special characters and quotation marks shown as Unicode "unknown char", `?`) when browsing the mirror.

The problem turned to be related to the different servers encoding, rather than depending on `wget`. The original server was a old Windows+IIS installation configured to serve HTML pages with ISO-8859 encoding, while the mirror was an Linux+Apache server configured to serve UTF-8 pages.

The solution was to configure Apache to serve ISO-8859 pages, adding to the right virtual host the directive `AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1`